# Importing Bazel Project fails in CLion on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, clion, bazel, macos-high-sierra

I installed Bazel plugin on my CLion and am trying to import a new Bazel C++  project and I keep hitting into these errors-

**tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0lft1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

```
ERROR: error loading package '': 
Encountered error while reading extension file 'requirements.bzl': no such package '@my_deps//': Traceback (most recent call last):     
File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_pmanjunath/0f9184e7a61c3740275307da0cc42014/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl", line 39       _pip_import_impl(repository_ctx, "python")
File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_pmanjunath/0f9184e7a61c3740275307da0cc42014/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl", line 35, in _pip_import_impl      fail(("pip_import failed: %s (%s)" % ...)))
pip_import failed:  (tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0lft1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. ).
```

On googling I found people were having this problem on their linux boxes and the solution was to upgrade `pip`. I did try

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

but to no avail. I am suspecting that it is picking up the wrong `.whl` file since the name clearly states its for `linux_x86_64`.

Any ideas?

Comment: try giving `rm -rf ~/.cache/bazel` a try the build again. Bazel, in my experience, will cache settings from bad/misconfigured builds.

Comment: @Taekahn I tried. Still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it reads `tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0lft1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` -> which means `cp27` & `linux` (obviously the wrong platform).

here would be a wheel file for MacOS: [tensorflow-1.10.0-py2-none-any.whl](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-py2-none-any.whl)

it is version `1.10.0`, but it might suffice to meet the dependency; to be installed alike:

```
python2 -m pip install tensorflow-1.10.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

found at [Installing TensorFlow on macOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package). in case the wheel file in version `1.10.0` should not meet the dependencies, "Plan B" would be to check out from [branch 1.10.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.10), in order to build from source.

Comment: Finally! The actual problem is very specific to my build env. Our build environment is tailor-made for Linux machines and hence there are a lot of dependencies missing on OS X. But this `whl` file issue didn't let bazel proceed at all. After using the `whl` file you suggested, bazel was able to make progress!!!

There were still a lot of errors because of the Linux specific dependency, but Sync at least completed.


Here's your +200 bounty!! Thank you!

Comment: @PavanManjunath glad to hear & thanks for the reputation. so far I've only installed it to Linux, in order to build TF for Android. therefore I wen't through some of these issues before already and in principle, this was merely a `pip` question, which I could still answer "just in time".